# How to record/output messages from a hooked DLL in Win32?

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

I have a Win32 GUI app where a thread starts upon pressing a button like so:

```cpp
...
        switch (wmId)
        {

            case int(BTN::Test) :
                CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)dllTest, &hWnd, 0, NULL);
...

HHOOK hhookSysMsg = nullptr;
HINSTANCE hinstDLL = nullptr;

void dllTest() {
    HOOKPROC hkprcSysMsg;
    
    hinstDLL = LoadLibraryA("F:\\projects\\_dll_hook\\x64\\Release\\hook.dll");

    if (hinstDLL == NULL) {
        prnt("Error loading dll: #%d", PV, GetLastError()); 
        return;
    }

    hkprcSysMsg = (HOOKPROC)GetProcAddress(hinstDLL, "SysMessageProc");
    if (hkprcSysMsg == NULL) {
        prnt("Error getting address of dll.SysMessageProc: #%d", PV, GetLastError());
        return;
    }

    hhookSysMsg = SetWindowsHookExA(
        WH_CALLWNDPROC,
        hkprcSysMsg,
        hinstDLL,
        0);
    if (hhookSysMsg == NULL) {
        prnt("Error hooking dll.SysMessageProc: #%d", PV, GetLastError());
        return;
    }

    Sleep(5000);

    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhookSysMsg);

    FreeLibrary(hinstDLL);

}
```

and here's DLL code:

```cpp
std::unordered_map<int, std::string> map;

void loadMsg() {
    std::fstream stream("F:\\tmp\\_dll\\msg.txt");
    if (stream.is_open()) {
        std::string line;
        while (std::getline(stream, line)) {
            auto index = line.find(' ');
            if (index != std::string::npos)
                map.insert(std::make_pair(std::stoi(line.substr(0, index)), line.substr(index + 1)));
        }
        stream.close();
    }
}

INT APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hDLL, DWORD Reason, LPVOID Reserved) {

    switch (Reason) {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        OutputDebugStringA("DLL attach function called");
        loadMsg();
        break;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        OutputDebugStringA("DLL detach function called");
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        OutputDebugStringA("DLL thread attach function called");
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        OutputDebugStringA("DLL thread detach function called");
        break;
    }

    return TRUE;
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) auto SysMessageProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode < 0) return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);

    if (nCode == HC_ACTION) {

        CWPSTRUCT* pCWP = (CWPSTRUCT*)lParam;

        HWND hWnd = pCWP->hwnd;

        char wclass[256]; wclass[0] = 0;

        if (GetClassNameA(hWnd, wclass, 255) != 0) {

            std::string msg = map[pCWP->message];
            
            if (1 || msg == "WM_NOTIFY") {
                char out[256]; out[0] = 0;
                sprintf_s(out, 255, "class: '%s', msg: %s %08X\n", wclass, msg.c_str(), pCWP->message);
                OutputDebugStringA(out);
            }
        }

    }
    

    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

This code works but it never prints out (in DebugView or MSVS Debug Output) messages from other programs (like Notepad).

If I replace OutputDebugStringA with output to a file, the target program and explorer.exe often crash or the program freezes. But then if I look at the file, I can see that messages from different programs were captured there.

So what is the right way to display messages in this case, so it's fast and captures messages from other programs, like it's done in Spy++ ?

Comment: You could try Mark Russinovich's [DebugView utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview).

Comment: As I mentioned, I do use that program to see debug output as well as inside MSVS

Comment: Oh, so you do - sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Your `dllTest()` function does not match the signature that `CreateThread()` is expecting for [its thread callback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms686736(v=vs.85)). So already, your code has **undefined behavior** before it even touches the DLL.

Get rid of the `(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)` type-cast and you will see the compiler complain about the mismatch. The correct declaration is:

```c
DWORD WINAPI dllTest(LPVOID)
```

Your DLL's `SysMessageProc()` function is declared incorrectly. too. So that is another source of **undefined behavior**.  The correct declaration is:

```c
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) LRESULT CALLBACK SysMessageProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
```

Also, there is no reason to convert `pCWP->message` to a `std::string` just to compare its value.  You can compare it as-is instead:

```c
if (1 || pCWP->message == WM_NOTIFY)
```

Comment: I made those changes, I still get exactly the same behavior - debug string output doesn't capture other program messages and file output does but crashes programs. I turn messages into strings for convenience so I can read them.

Comment: @use You can have Visual Studio's debugger convert message ID's to symbolic constants using the Watch window. Just add the value in question (e.g. a variable or constant value) followed by the `,wm` format option, something like `pCWP->message,wm`. That relieves you of having a global `std::unordered_map`. It's entirely likely for that object's constructor to cause a crash. You certainly don't want to run arbitrary code under the loader lock (which, incidentally, this does).

Comment: @iinspectable thanks, that approach seems to make it stable and I can now see all messages in the file, I'll accept it as the answer if you write one.

Comment: @use I'm not convinced that removing the global (with a non-trivial c'tor) is sufficient. There's still the call to `loadMsg` executing under the loader lock, that can easily deadlock a process. Did you remove that as well?

Comment: yes I completely removed everything related to that map including the function and the call to it.